# replace image within a button JS

Tags: javascript, image, button

I have a rather tricky question with a looong story, hopefully I can convey it well enough without much background.

I am restricted to working within a predefined form that allows me to change minor css and add javascript etc. however there are portions of the source code I can not edit.

Within this form there is a button that has an image embedded inside it. I would like to use some javascript to either remove this image or replace the src with " " and keep the functionality of the button.

button source is:

> ```
>    <button type="submit" id="ID_formd1735f95_guest_login_submit">
>     <img src="images/icon-tick22.png" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align:middle;" alt=""> Log In
>    </button>
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not the best way to solve this issue. Have you tried to prevent adding this image inside the button ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann: Did you read the part that said there were portions of the source that can't be edited?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, but the question is. Why?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann: Well, I can't speak for the OP, but I've been in awful environments where bits of markup are generated by systems outside my control, and to which I'm not allowed to do anything before it hits the client side.  So I've seen similar requirements.  I'm very glad to be away from such environments now, but they are not all that rare, I'm afraid.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann, ScottSauyet is correct, this is a system generated button that I have no control over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not too difficult:  http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/kN6WV/

```
var button = document.getElementById("ID_formd1735f95_guest_login_submit");
var images = button.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
if (images && images.length) {
    button.removeChild(images[0]);
}​
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and link, jsfiddle looks like an invaluble tool!
the downside is, even though it appears to work on jsfiddle, I can not replicate it (copy and paste)...

Comment: my apologies! this does work... just not in IE 8.
I think I can live with that, but if anyone has any developments on how to get it working in IE that would be awesome

Comment: The Fiddle works in IE8, not sure why it doesn't work in your environment.

Comment: So far this has been the only solution that has provided a fix, marking as answered, thanks Scott